# py2exe not a valid win32 application

Tags: pyside, py2exe

I know this topic has been discussed before but it looks like none of the solutions work for me.

I have created a python application using [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) and a few other modules.
When I compile the app, I don't see any error and it runs without issue on any 64 bit machine.

However, when I try to launch it from a 32 bit XP machine I get

```
py2exe not a valid win32 application
```

I am aware that the DLL's have to be included (which I did saved in the dist folder with Microsoft sub-folder) but I am still seeing a message in the CMD window that certain DLL's are not included.

Is this a standard message? A sort of reminder or would this message disappear if all dll's are included? I do not get any errors.

So thats where my confusion is coming from.
I also did a few Google searches regarding other compilers and came across [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) which apparently does not work with [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

**py2exe log**:

```
*** binary dependencies ***

Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
   WINMM.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
   MSVCR100.dll - C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
   WSOCK32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
   MSVCP100.dll - C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP100.dll
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   WINSPOOL.DRV - C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
   GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually had nothing to do with the MVS DLL's!
The DLL issue was related to Pyside.
Even though I downloaded 32 bit version from the Pyside page the problem was only fixed once I installed the 32 bit Pyside Binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the EXEs/DLLs are 64 bit builds? Check that you are deploying the correct architecture executables to your 32-bit Windows XP machine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That was my assumption too, so I removed everything and reinstalled python and py2exe 32 bit.. Now after building I cant even run it on my own (64 bit) machine.

Comment: A log file is created containing the following content:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KruttschnittGmbH.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "Splash.pyc", line 1, in <module>
  File "PySide\QtGui.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "PySide\QtGui.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Do you have the correct DLLs for pyqt deployed to your 64 bit development machine?

Comment: Hi Cameron,
I installed the vcredist_x86.exe and then copied it from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT. So it must be 32 bit.